# urllib.quote DOT character( . ) in python

Tags: python, urllib

I am trying to use `urllib.quote` on DOT character `(.)` in python but am not getting my desired outptut.

```
>>> urllib.quote(".")
'.'
>>> urllib.quote_plus(".")
'.'
```

but when I unquote `%2E` using `urllib.unquote` I get

```
>>> urllib.unquote("%2E")
'.'
```

So, my question is why am I not able to get `%2E` as my output when I use `quote or quote_plus` on `.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dots do not need to be escaped. However, `unquote` converts all `%xx` characters since it is perfectly valid to encode any character, no matter if necessary or not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you point me to the correct documentation.

Comment: @Noob: "Letters, digits, and the characters '`_.-`' are never quoted" -- http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote

Answer (score 2):

The link for Reference is
http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html
 '_.-' doesn't require a quote.